# Whether tinyurl can be used to fetch json data from socrata

Tags: socrata, tinyurl

Does the socrata support tinyurl or any urlshortener service to fetch data if the query string is too long. Please correct if I am wrong

Answer (score 1):

The query string will still be too long, url shortening services just perform a redirect with the original query and so in the end it is exactly the same.